# Spring MVC + DisplayTag + Checkbox

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

I have to integrate in a SpringMVC form a set of fields and a List handled by a Display:table .

In the display table I have to view a column of checkboxes where the information about if this is checked or not is passed by the controller. I have to manipulate this checkboxes and pass them to another controller to store that data inside a DB.

I'm simulating this situation creating a SpringMVC controller that set me inside the Model some data :

```
package it.test.displaytag.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import it.test.displaytag.model.Bean;
import it.test.displaytag.model.Interno;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(value = "index.htm")
public String home(Model model) {

    Bean bean = new Bean();
    bean.setCognome("Cognome");
    bean.setNome("Nome");

    ArrayList<Interno> list = new ArrayList<Interno>();

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
        Interno asd = new Interno();
        asd.setIdCheck(i);
        if (i%2==0) {
            asd.setIsEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
        list.add(asd);
    }
    bean.setInterno(list);
    model.addAttribute("displayTagForm", bean);
    return "index";
}

}
```

The JSP is :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<%
org.displaytag.decorator.CheckboxTableDecorator decorator = new org.displaytag.decorator.CheckboxTableDecorator();
    decorator.setId("idCheck");
    decorator.setFieldName("_chk");
    pageContext.setAttribute("checkboxDecorator", decorator);
%>
<html>
<body>

<form:form name="displayTagForm" action="/salva" modelAttribute="displayTagForm" method="POST">

Form di test per testare la paginazione nelle Displaytag.
<br><br>
Nome : <form:input path="nome" />
<br><form:input path = "cognome" />

<br><br>
Tabella
<br><center>
<display:table name="displayTagForm.interno" uid="bean" decorator = "checkboxDecorator"
     pagesize="10" >
    <display:column property="idCheck" />
    <display:column property = "checkbox" />
</display:table>
</center>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

The JSP is correctly showing the informations inside the fields "nome" and "cognome" but is not showing if the checkbox is selected or not ( passed with a flag isEnabled in the bean ) . I've not understood how to do this trick.

After that, i Have to handle the pagination and the sort of the display:table, because I think that if I write something in that 2 textboxes nome and cognome and I click one of the link to go to another page, I lose the informations that i've written in the textboxes and I lose the information about the value of the checkbox clicked or not.

How can I handle this situation ?

Comment: This is not asp-classic.

Comment: @Martha They probably put in asp which get's aliased to asp-classic, whereas they meant asp.net

Comment: No, sorry, autocorrect ... it was JSP :)